# sql server 2014 Why do I get the error with the code in a view and not stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

When I try to add the following code to a view:

```
SELECT [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].AnaUnica,
       [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].Albo,
       [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].Comune,
       [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].ComunePDC,
       IIf([Comune] <> [ComunePDC], 'NO', 'OK') AS Attenzione,
       [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].Paghe,
       [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].ContOrd,
       [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].ContSem
FROM   [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati]
WHERE  ( ( ( [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].ComunePDC ) <> 'Extra Provincia' )
         AND ( ( IIf([Comune] <> [ComunePDC], 'NO', 'OK') ) = 'NO' ) );
```

I get the error:

> Error in list of function arguments: '<' not recognized. 
>   Unable to parse query text.

But when I add the same code in a stored procedure I get no error.

What is the reason for the difference in behaviour?

Comment: This would not appear to be caused by the query you have shown, for the simple reason that it does not have the token `<` in it.

Comment: there is a '<>'   ... if you actually read the query.

Comment: That code parses fine in SQL Server 2014. What is `@@version`? Also how are you trying to create the view? That doesn't sound like a SQL Server error message you would encounter running `CREATE VIEW` directly.

Comment: Use microsoft sql server management studio. open a db. go to views. Add a new view. Paste that code in and try to save the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from the visual designer. This apparently hasn't been updated to cope with the more recent syntax additions.

Don't use that. It is buugy and very limited anyway. Just open a new query window and execute

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.SomeName
AS
/*Paste your code here*/
```

and it will  work fine if you are on a version later than 2012.

There are no actual syntax errors in your code though there are several things that can be improved.

Fixing the formatting, removing the unneeded two part names and simplifying the `WHERE` clause and `SELECT` list results in

```
SELECT AnaUnica,
       Albo,
       Comune,
       ComunePDC,
       'NO' AS Attenzione, /*Guaranteed by the WHERE that [Comune] <> [ComunePDC]*/
       Paghe,
       ContOrd,
       ContSem
FROM   dbo.[Albi-Anagrafe-Associati]
WHERE  ComunePDC NOT IN ('Extra Provincia',Comune);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is so complicated to read.  Have you heard of table aliases?

```
SELECT aa.AnaUnica, aa.Albo, aa.Comune, aa.ComunePDC,
       (case when Comune <> ComunePDC then 'NO' end 'OK' end ) AS Attenzione,
       aa.Paghe, aa.ContOrd, aa.ContSem
FROM [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati] aa
WHERE (aa.ComunePDC <> 'Extra Provincia' AND
      Comune <> ComunePDC ;  -- May need to check for `NULL` as well
```

Notes:

- If you can't read a query, you really can't do much with it.  Write your queries so you can read them.
- Short table aliases (the abbreviates for the table names) make the query easier to write and to read.
- Over-use of parentheses doesn't help either.
- I much prefer `CASE` to `IIF()` because the former is ANSI standard SQL and the latter is for back-compatibility to MS Access.

Comment: Im converting from MS Access to SQL Server 2014. Now Sql Server 2014 has got a built in IIF function.. according to the docs. And I want to keep the query code as close to the original as possible

Comment: Also there is no missing ] as far as I can see

Comment: Can even add this code to a view: SELECT IIF(1 > 0,'True','False') AS 'Output'

Comment: This says it cant be done... https://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/620781-can-i-use-if-condition-view

Comment: @Eminem - That is dated 2007. `IIF` didn't exist in SQL Server until 2012

Comment: BTW there are no missing brackets. The one you indicated is matched by the one I highlighted here http://i.stack.imgur.com/tDJfY.png